# How can I use CMake on command line? - Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, cl

I want to run CMake on a Windows machine on the command line. The problem is that using Visual Studio as the generator works fine, but when using Ninja, CMake cannot find the specified compiler (cl.exe). I have been able to get around this by calling `vcvarsall.bat x64` on the command line before I run the `cmake` command, but shouldn't there be an easier way? [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170#:%7E:text=Sourcing%20the%20environment%20when%20building%20with%20command%2Dline%20generators%20on%20Windows) seems to suggest that this is the proper way.

**Is there a way to invoke `vcvarsall.bat` in a `CMakePresets.json` file?** Alternatively, since I am using VS Code, is there a way to have presets for VS Code so I can select what development enviroment I want? Sort of like a `presets.json` file, but for VS Code?

I have tried adding `cl.exe` to my `PATH`, but whenever doing this, there are other environment variables that also need set up.

I should also mention that none of this setup process needs to be done on Linux. Is there any way for Windows to always be able to access the necessary c++ files?

Finally, my motivation for all of this is to eventually use Intel's c++ compiler (icx.exe). Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Here is what the not working configuration in my `CMakePresets.json` file looks like:

```json
{
    "name": "Ninja - MSVC",
    "displayName": "Ninja - MSVC",
    "description": "Ninja with MSVC compiler",
    "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/_build",
    "generator": "Ninja",
    "cacheVariables": {"CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl", "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl"},
    "condition": {"type": "equals", "lhs": "${hostSystemName}", "rhs": "Windows"},
    "vendor": {
        "microsoft.com/VisualStudioSettings/CMake/1.0": {
            "hostOS": "Windows"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC there should be a command-line item in the start-menu under Visual Studio. This basically starts a command prompt with the BAT script. Use that instead?

Comment: ***I have been able to get around this by calling vcvarsall.bat x64 on the command line before I run the cmake command, but shouldn't there be an easier way?*** I always run CMake from a Visual Studio Command prompt which I now have setup in my Windows Terminal. In the past I just had a shortcut in my build tree that I would click on to start a cmd.exe window with the proper settings for my compiler. Both methods at some point execute vcvarsall.bat

Comment: Or invoke [`cmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) with the `/k` argument and the path to the `vcvarsall.bat` file?

Comment: Have you tried using the [cmake plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)? I've not used it on windows but I think it'll setup the compiler for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several workflows to simplify this process for me:

1. I found that the comment by [Alan Birtles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956820/how-can-i-use-cmake-on-command-line-windows#:%7E:text=Have%20you%20tried%20using%20the%20cmake%20plugin%3F%20I%27ve%20not%20used%20it%20on%20windows%20but%20I%20think%20it%27ll%20setup%20the%20compiler%20for%20you) is the most user friendly approach to improving my workflow. The recommendation was to use the [CMake Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) for VS Code which easily scans your system for compilers and you can use options in the bottom bar of VS Code to set up your project. On top of this, there are a bunch of settings for the extension in VS Code to customize the tool to your needs. This is by far the easiest to use, and it is the easiest to implement across different platforms and users.
2. The second option was to run CMake directly in a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, but the disadvantage of this approach compared to the first is that you still have to type out your CMake commands.
3. The final option is to run vcvarsall.bat x64 on startup of VS Code with a tasks.json file, but this option requires that you specify the path of the bat file, which isn't always portable.